# Gerar escala de duas pessoas por dias determinados

Tags: javascript

Tenho um documento para fazer todos os meses, nesse documento é apresentado uma escala de três dias ( *Domingo*, *Quinta* e *Sábado* ) de cada semana, **duas pessoas diferentes** serão escalas em cada dia dessa semana:

```
let Pessoas = ["Fulano 0", "Fulano 1", "Fulano 2", "Fulano 3", "Fulano 4", "Fulano 5", "Fulano 6"]
```

A escala seria como:

```
08-03-2018 - Fulano 0 / Fulano 5
10-03-2018 - Fulano 6 / Fulano 2
11-03-2018 - Fulano 1 / Fulano 3
```

O problema é que o objeto `Pessoas` não tem um tamanho fixo, e no momento ele tem **sete** pessoas cadastradas o que pode variar para menos ou para mais.

Nesse sorteio não pode haver duplicatas, ou seja:

```
08-03-2018 - Fulano 0 / Fulano 0
```

Também não pode haver como no exemplo abaixo, sem que todas as combinações possíveis seja alcançada.

```
08-03-2018 - Fulano 0 / Fulano 5
10-03-2018 - Fulano 6 / Fulano 2
11-03-2018 - Fulano 0 / Fulano 5
```

Usando a biblioteca [moment-weekdaysin](https://github.com/kodie/moment-weekdaysin), consegui recuperar os *Domingos*, as *Quintas* e os *Sábados* do mês atual com o código abaixo:

```
let datas = moment().weekdaysInMonth([0, 4, 6]);
datas.forEach(data => {
  Resultado.push({
    data: data.format('L'),
  })
});
```

O retorno é:

```
[
  { "data": "03/01/2018" }, { "data": "03/03/2018" },
  { "data": "03/04/2018" }, { "data": "03/08/2018" },
  { "data": "03/10/2018" }, { "data": "03/11/2018" },
  { "data": "03/15/2018" }, { "data": "03/17/2018" },
  { "data": "03/18/2018" }, { "data": "03/22/2018" },
  { "data": "03/24/2018" }, { "data": "03/25/2018" },
  { "data": "03/29/2018" }, { "data": "03/31/2018" }
]
```

O meu problema está na hora de sortear as pessoas pois se eu utilizar o código abaixo, ele ira retornar **sete** pessoas sorteadas sendo que necessito apenas de **duas**, outra coisa que acontece com o código abaixo é que após o primeiro `loop` os demais contém o mesmos valores sorteados nesse primeiro.

```
escala: Pessoa.sort(_ => {
  return .7 - Math.random()
})
```

> Pode ver funcionando em [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qkkbxg?file=index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Eu vi que esse método que você está usando para "embaralhar" o array, não é muito indicado, veja esse post do SO inglês:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650169/8133067
>
> [community edit: This answer is incorrect; see comments. It is being left here for future reference because the idea is not that rare.]
>
> ```
> [1,2,3,4,5,6].sort(function() {
>   return .5 - Math.random();
> });
> ```

Peguei então uma outra resposta para essa mesma questão no SO inglês:

> How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/8133067

Para montar essa função:

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length;
  var newArray = array.slice();
  var temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = newArray[currentIndex];
    newArray[currentIndex] = newArray[randomIndex];
    newArray[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return newArray;
}
```

Criei também essa outra função:

```
function getPessoaSorteada(pessoas, pessoasSorteadas) {
  if (pessoasSorteadas.length == 0)
    pessoasSorteadas = shuffle(pessoas);
  return pessoasSorteadas.pop();
}
```

E modifiquei aquela parte do seu código em que o Resultado é montado, ficando assim:

```
var pessoasSorteadas = [];
var pessoa1, pessoa2;
datas.forEach(data => {
  pessoa1 = getPessoaSorteada(Pessoa, pessoasSorteadas);
  pessoa2 = getPessoaSorteada(Pessoa, pessoasSorteadas);
  if (pessoa2==pessoa1)
    pessoa2 = getPessoaSorteada(Pessoa, pessoasSorteadas);
  Resultado.push({
    data: data.format('L'),
    diaSemana: semana[data.day()],
    escala: [pessoa1, pessoa2]
  })
});
```

Explicando:
Crio uma cópia do array de pessoas e a embaralho, para fazer o sorteio. A cada dia desejado, eu uso duas pessoas dessa lista e as removo de lá, quando a lista (array) fica sem pessoas, crio novamente uma cópia embaralhada da lista de pessoas. Só checo para não acontecer da última pessoa da lista anterior ser igual à primeira da lista atual.

Dessa forma acho que o resultado ficou do jeito que você queria. Era isso mesmo?

**EDIT:**
Eu percebi que havia um furo na minha primeira sugestão: se, por coincidência, calhasse da última pessoa sorteada de uma rodada ser igual a primeira pessoa usada da lista da rodada seguinte, eu simplesmente ignorava essa pessoa e usava a próxima da lista, para não haver repetição, mas aí essa pessoa não seria escalada nessa rodada seguinte, ou seja, seria uma rodada de 6 pessoas apenas, ao invés de 7.

Pensei em um novo esquema, então, em que no caso de repetição, ao invés de pular a pessoa, eu recrio a lista de sorteados, quantas vezes for necessário, até que a última pessoa não se repita. Assim, terei sempre uma lista completa, com as 7 pessoas, e sem "dobradinha" de ninguém.

Para isso, mudei essa função:

```
function getPessoaSorteada(pessoas, pessoasSorteadas, ultimaPessoaSorteada) {
  if (pessoasSorteadas.length == 0) {
    pessoasSorteadas = shuffle(pessoas);
    while (ultimaPessoaSorteada == pessoasSorteadas[pessoasSorteadas.length - 1])
      pessoasSorteadas = shuffle(pessoas);
  }
  return pessoasSorteadas.pop();
}
```

E mudei também o trecho que monta o resultado:

```
var pessoasSorteadas = [];
var pessoa1, pessoa2;
datas.forEach(data => {
  pessoa1 = getPessoaSorteada(Pessoa, pessoasSorteadas, pessoa2);
  pessoa2 = getPessoaSorteada(Pessoa, pessoasSorteadas, pessoa1);
  Resultado.push({
    data: data.format('L'),
    diaSemana: semana[data.day()],
    escala: [pessoa1, pessoa2]
  })
});
```

**EDIT 2:**
Havia um outro problema no código que eu propus: A função `getPessoaSorteada()` recriava o array `pessoasSorteadas` quando ele ficava vazio, mas, no Javascript aparentemente não há como passar um argumento **por referência** (*by ref*), então, quando eu recriava o array dentro da função, ele não era devolvido para o código que chamou a função, logo, o array estava sendo recriado o tempo todo, causando diversas repetições nas pessoas sorteadas:

```
function getPessoaSorteada(pessoas, pessoasSorteadas, ultimaPessoaSorteada) {
  // ...
    // Essa linha criava um novo array, que não era 
    // devolvido através do argumento da função.
    pessoasSorteadas = shuffle(pessoas);
  // ...
}
```

Eu tinha achado estranho porque quando eu testei o código ele funcionou, mas aí descobri também porque antes ele funcionou: Eu tinha escrito errado o nome do parâmetro da função, escrevi `pesoasSorteadas` (com um 's' só), mas no corpo da função eu estava usando o nome correto, `pessoasSorteadas`. Como a variável do código que chamava a função também tinha o mesmo nome, `pessoasSorteadas`, e estava num escopo "global", acho que ele estava usando dentro da função a variável que foi definida fora dela.

A solução que encontrei foi preencher o array passado como argumento para a função com os valores do novo array, assim o array é retornado pelo argumento, já que não é recriado, e, portanto, continua sendo o mesmo objeto. Para isso usei como base essa resposta no [SO<sup>en</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4156156/8133067), então o trecho que antes era assim:

```
function getPessoaSorteada(pessoas, pessoasSorteadas, ultimaPessoaSorteada) {
  // ...
    // Essa linha criava um novo array, que não era 
    // devolvido através do argumento da função.
    pessoasSorteadas = shuffle(pessoas);
  // ...
}
```

agora ficou assim:

```
function getPessoaSorteada(pessoas, pessoasSorteadas, ultimaPessoaSorteada) {
  // ...
    // Agora ao invés de criar um novo array em cima do argumento
    // 'pessoasSorteadas', o mesmo objeto (array) passado para a
    // função é populado com os elementos do novo array, com as 
    // pessoas sorteadas, criado pela função shuffle(pessoas).
    pessoasSorteadas.push.apply(sorteadas, shuffle(pessoas));
  // ...
}
```

A função toda ficou assim, então:

```
function getPessoaSorteada(pessoas, pessoasSorteadas, ultimaPessoaSorteada) {
  if (pessoasSorteadas.length == 0) {
    pessoasSorteadas.push.apply(pessoasSorteadas, shuffle(pessoas));
    while (ultimaPessoaSorteada == pessoasSorteadas[pessoasSorteadas.length - 1])
      pessoasSorteadas.push.apply(pessoasSorteadas, shuffle(pessoas));
  }
  return pessoasSorteadas.pop();
}
```

Comment: Ainda assim ele está as mesmas pessoas em seguida `03/04/2018 - Fulano 1 / Fulano 2    03/08/2018 - Fulano 1 / Fulano 2` ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qkkbxg?file=index.html

Comment: Estranho, ontem quando testei estava funcionando direitinho, agora realmente tem algo de errado,, depois dou uma olhada.

Comment: Descobri o problema, e porque ontem funcionou, vou editar a resposta (EDIT 2).

Comment: E agora, funcionou?